# tensorflow python 3.7.2 import error with anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, anaconda

This is the error i got on my Windows Terminal. Please help me out to get out of this problem. Thanks in Advance. :) 
In the Pip install step everything was installed Correctly .

```
>>> `import tensorflow`
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in _find_and_load
SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2019-02-20 13:58:39.960202: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr
```

Comment: Could you please check the version of numpy .?

If numpy version is  below 1.16 try to upgrade the version to 1.16 as 

pip install numpy==1.16
or
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy==1.16